# How to achieve Java.Lang.IRunnable in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, scrollview, postdelayed

I want to identify the scroll end action, which could not be achieved through the existing APIs from ScrollView. Because, when we scrolled fast, event after the pointer/hand is taken, certain scrolling is took place on its own. My requirement is to catch the point when the scrolling is ended on its own.

I can achieve this scenario in Xamarin.Android implementing Java.Lang.IRunnable in a custom class and by using the Run() method in it. I need to achieve this in Xamarin iOS.

Could you please provide a valid suggestion for this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "DecelerationEnded" event in UIScrollViewer to achieve your requirement.